# Converting a dictionary including lists with different lengths to a 2-column dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this one

```
my_dict = {0:[1,2],
           1:[1, 5, 100,120],
           2:[1, 89, 90, 1625, 98, 0, 10]}
```

I want to convert it to a data frame with just two columns like this one.

```
col1 col2
0   [1, 2]
1   [1, 5, 100,120]
2   [1, 89, 90, 1625, 98, 0, 10]
```

The second column includes a list of numbers. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

```
#Input dictionary
my_dict = {0:[1,2],
           1:[1, 5, 100,120],
           2:[1, 89, 90, 1625, 98, 0, 10]}

#Convert dictionary to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict.items(),columns=["col1","col2"])

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   col1                          col2
0     0                        [1, 2]
1     1              [1, 5, 100, 120]
2     2  [1, 89, 90, 1625, 98, 0, 10]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s=pd.Series(my_dict).reset_index()
Out[32]: 
   index                             0
0      0                        [1, 2]
1      1              [1, 5, 100, 120]
2      2  [1, 89, 90, 1625, 98, 0, 10]
```